# Let $G$ be a group of order $p^n, p$ prime. Then $G$ has a composition series such that all its composition factors are of order $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is an example from a book. But I don't understand the solution.

Let $G$ be a group of order $p^n, p$ prime. Then $G$ has a composition series such that all its composition factors are of order $p$.

*Solution.* Clearly, any composition factor is of order $p^k$ for some $k >0$. But since a group of prime power order has a nontrivial center, and each composition factor is a simple group, it follows that each composition factor is a simple abelian group and therefore, of order $p$.

I don't see how the fact that the group has a nontrivial center, and each composition factor is a simple group leads to the conclution that each composition factor is a simple abelian group. Can anyone elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be a composition factor. You know it is a simple group, and that $Z(C) \ne \{ 1 \}$. Then you must have $Z(C) = C$. i.e., $C$ is abelian. Now a finite abelian group is only simple when it has prime order, for instance by Cauchy's Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

**Theorem:** A group $\;G\;$  of order $\;p^n\;$ has  **normal subgroup** of order $\;p^k\;$ , for all $\;0\le k\le n\;$.

**Highlights of proof:** by induction, the decisive inductive step being to remark that $\;Z(G)\neq1\;$ and thus there exists $\;1\neq z\in Z(G)\;$  and look at the quotient $\;G/\langle z\rangle\;$ ...